# Вывести пользователей Mysql

Tags: mysql

Как вывести всех пользователей, которых я не лайнкул в таблице likes и соответствую условию

накидал так, но ничего не выводит

```
SELECT * FROM `users`
LEFT join `user_attributes` on user_attributes.user_id = users.id
left join likes on likes.like_user != users.id and likes.user_id = 1
where user_attributes.gender = 2 and user_attributes.city = "Витебск" and user_attributes.age BETWEEN 18 and 25 LIMIT 4
```

Comment: может `!=` надо на равно заменить? Используйте `inner join` и перенесите туда все свои условия фильтрации.

Comment: нужно вывести пользователей, которых я не лайкнул, ели поставить = то я буду выводить всех кого лайкнул

Comment: `FROM users LEFT JOIN likes ... WHERE likes.??? IS NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
left join likes on likes.like_user != users.id and likes.user_id = 1
```

Очень странная строчка. Без приложенной схемы таблиц сложно понять, то мне кажется дело еще в том, что у вас есть `likes.like_user` и `likes.user_id`. И если вы связываете по `users.id`, то чисто по логике надо вязать с `likes.user_id`

```
SELECT * FROM `users`
LEFT join `user_attributes` on user_attributes.user_id = users.id
left join likes on likes.user_id = users.id
where user_attributes.gender = 2 and user_attributes.city = "Витебск" and likes.user_id is null and user_attributes.age BETWEEN 18 and 25 LIMIT 4
```

upd:

Ну тогда так.

```
SELECT * FROM `users`
LEFT join `user_attributes` on user_attributes.user_id = users.id
left join likes on likes.like_user = users.id 
where user_attributes.gender = 2 and user_attributes.city = "Витебск" and likes.like_user is null and likes.user_id = 1 and user_attributes.age BETWEEN 18 and 25 LIMIT 4
```

Comment: likes.user_id это мой id, а likes.like_user эт id кого я лайкнул и мне нужно подтягивать тех пользоватлей, которых я еще не лайкал

Comment: @Aslero обновил. В следующий раз прилагайте схемы с разъяснениями. А лучше используйте fiddle

Comment: прекратите писать условия джойна в where. используйте inner с соответствующими условиями

Answer (score 1):

вот так еще накидал

```
SELECT * FROM `users`
LEFT join `user_attributes` on user_attributes.user_id = users.id
where 
user_attributes.gender = 2
and user_attributes.city = "Витебск"
and user_attributes.age BETWEEN 18 and 35
        and not exists (select * from likes where likes.like_user = users.id)
LIMIT 4
```